# Rails: eager-loading on an already-left-joined table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

We are already left-joining a table so that we can order by a column, if the relation exists:

```
people = Person
  .joins("LEFT JOIN addresses ON addresses.id = people.address_id")
  .order("addresses.country")
  .all
```

This results in a single SQL query, but I'd like to have `people.first.address` not trigger SQL to load the address. I am left-joining because some people don't have addresses.

`.includes(:address)` triggers a separate query.

You can do what I'm suggesting with inner joins, using `includes`, but that triggers 2 SQL queries:

```
Person.includes(:address).all
```

While `joins` + `includes` triggers only one (but INNER joins):

```
Person.joins(:address).includes(:address).all
```

Active record also uses left joins if you force a join while eager-loading 
 `.eager_load(:addresses)`.

Can you take an existing left-join and have rails eager-load with those results? So far I can't find this.

Comment: Does Person have_one :address or have_many :addresses ?

Comment: person `has_many :addresses`, yeah

Comment: My answer below is for person has_one address, but the has_many behaves the same.

Comment: @swajak Please see my answer below.  It shows the easy `ActiveRecord` supported way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
people = Person.
  eager_load(:address).
  merge(Address.order("coalesce(country, '')")).
  all

people.first.address
```

`eager_load` forces eager loading by performing a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

I added a coalesce on country so you have more control over where people without addresses appear in the results.

Here is what it looks like for me:

```
people = Person.
  eager_load(:address).
  merge(Address.order("coalesce(country, '')")).
  all

(0.5ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "people"."id") FROM "people" LEFT OUTER JOIN "addresses" ON "addresses"."person_id" = "people"."id"
SQL (2.1ms)  SELECT "people"."id" AS t0_r0, "people"."name" AS t0_r1, "people"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "people"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "addresses"."id" AS t1_r0, "addresses"."person_id" AS t1_r1, "addresses"."address" AS t1_r2, "addresses"."country" AS t1_r3, "addresses"."created_at" AS t1_r4, "addresses"."updated_at" AS t1_r5 FROM "people" LEFT OUTER JOIN "addresses" ON "addresses"."person_id" = "people"."id" ORDER BY coalesce(addresses.country, '')


people.first.address
nil

people.last.address
#<Address:0x007febabb508a8> {
            :id => 1,
     :person_id => 4,
       :address => "24175 Gerhold Prairie",
       :country => "O",
    :created_at => Thu, 01 Feb 2018 18:47:45 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Thu, 01 Feb 2018 18:47:45 UTC +00:00
}
```

Note that no queries are run when you access the addresses

I'll point that you've ordered by a table that left outer joined, so you need to decide how you want to treat nulls.

Comment: Yours is the best answer so far, thank you. As I stated in the question, I know about `eager_load` but was hoping to avoid it because it alters the `SELECT` (rails selects all columns from each table) and turns it into an ugly, ginormous mess (and for multiple joins and hundreds of columns, quite a bit of IO). With `eager_load`, if I could somehow get the `SELECT` to end up being `SELECT people.*, addresses.*`, then I'd call it a day and pick this solution. As it is, I'll wait and see what else comes out of the woodwork.

Comment: If you look carefully at the SQL, its is people.*, addresses.*, but rails splats out all the column names with aliases (t0_r0 for first table, first column, t0_r1 for first table, second column, etc).    Using select people.*, addresses.* means you can end up with duplicate column names in the result set (created_at for instance).   Using explicit column aliases is more reliable.  I'm not sure I understand the IO overhead concern if you are selecting all the columns (people.*, addresses.*) vs having rails alias all the columns (t0_r0).  The SQL is bigger, but equivalent and less ambigous

Answer (score 4):

You can uses [`#references`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references) with [`#includes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) to `LEFT JOIN` your relation and achieve what you are after.

```
people = Person
  .includes(:addresses)
  .references(:addresses)
  .order("addresses.country")
```

This will yield one query and all the people, whether or not they have an address, and also eager load the addresses to avoid the dreaded N + 1 queries.

The documentation doesn't do a great job of explaining that `#references` will add a `LEFT JOIN` but it's purpose is to allow adding SQL clauses (`WHERE`, `ORDER`, `GROUP`, etc.) on the relation in conjunction with `#includes`.

Comment: Nicely answered! And I agree that the documentation on Reference messed up for sure!

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your case you could select your query creating an alias for the fields you are going to use from address something like this:

```
people = Person
         .joins("LEFT JOIN addresses ON addresses.id = people.address_id")
         .select("people.*, addresses.country as address_country")
         .order("address_country")
         .all
```

This won't change your desired query and will not result in extra queries, not for country at least.

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't super clear on this, but your solution will trigger a 2nd SQL if you do `people[0].address`. The part of the question I'm referencing: "This results in a single SQL query, but I'd like to have people.first.address not trigger SQL to load the address."